# ngx-datatable selecting both a row and a checkbox

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

So I have need to support both checkbox selection per row as well as selecting the row itself.
the problem is when I support checkbox selection I am not longer notified when a row is selected.
here is the code:

```
<ngx-datatable #table class="material dark"
               style="width: 90%"
               [rows]="rows"
               [columnMode]="'force'"
               [headerHeight]="50"
               [columns]="columns"
               [footerHeight]="50"
               rowHeight="auto"
               [limit]="50"
               [selected]="selected"
               [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
               [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false"
               [displayCheck]="displayCheck"
               (activate)="onActivate($event)"
               (onClick )="onClick($event)">
```

Now I am able to get both selection, per row and per checkbox since I added the (onClick), the problem is that I don't get the data object selected since onClick no longer get me any useful $event information (it has Input x y etc...)

Basically all I am trying to do is support both chebox selection (which works fine now) but at the same time support row selection and get the Object of the row of the selected row item when (onClick) is fired.

Thanks

Sean

Comment: What Angular version it it ? Try `(click)="onClick($event)"`

Comment: I did.. same results :(

Comment: What angular version do you use ? Library ngx-datatable you use is really old. XD

Comment: Angular latest 8.x and "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.2",

Comment: Why you are not using Angular Material ? https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: I do use both... each one has it's own benefits.

Comment: Oh ok i google wrong ngx-datatable XD This one should be ok. XD But i cant help you any more becouse i didnt use it. ;/

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so would you post the information for both the html and ts.

Answer (score 0):

I am achieving row selection on click and from checkbox by this.
It was just first attempt and I didn't tried to improve it so just deal with it.
The only trade off it has is that once a  row is selected it cannot be deselected. the only way is to select all and deselect all from header checkbox.
I hope this will help.

```
<ngx-datatable 
style="height:100%;" 
class="material" 
[rows]="rows" 
columnMode="force" 
[headerHeight]="40"
[loadingIndicator]="true" 
[rowHeight]="50" 
[trackByProp]="_id" 
[rowIdentity]="rowIdentity" 
[footerHeight]="50"
[scrollbarV]="true" 
[scrollbarH]="true" 
[virtualization]="true" 
[rowClass]="getRowClass" 
[selected]="checkboxedSkus"
[selectionType]="SelectionType.multi" 
[selectAllRowsOnPage]="false" 
(activate)="onActivate($event)"
(select)="selectListener($event)">

<ngx-datatable-column [width]="40" [sortable]="false" [canAutoResize]="false" [frozenLeft]="true"
  [headerCheckboxable]="true" [cellClass]="getCheckboxClass">
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template let-value="value" let-allRowsSelected="allRowsSelected"
    let-selectFn="selectFn">
    <label class="checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" class="ngx-datatable-checkbox" [checked]="allRowsSelected"
        (change)="selectFn(!allRowsSelected)" />
      <span class="checkmark header-checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value" let-isSelected="isSelected"
    let-onCheckboxChangeFn="onCheckboxChangeFn">
    <label class="checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" class="ngx-datatable-checkbox" [checked]="isSelected"
        (change)="onCheckboxChangeFn($event)" />
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>

<ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(col.prop === 'name') || (col.name === 'Status') ; else elseTemplate">
    <ngx-datatable-column [name]="col.name" [headerClass]="getHeaderClass" [cellClass]="getCellClass"
      [frozenLeft]="true" [prop]="col.prop"></ngx-datatable-column>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container>
    <ng-template #elseTemplate>
      <ngx-datatable-column [name]="col.name" [headerClass]="getHeaderClass" [prop]="col.prop">
      </ngx-datatable-column>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```